# Issue Connection to server using Remote-FTP atom package and Private Keys

Tags: ftp, sftp, remote-access, ssh-keys, private-key

I'm trying to connect to my server using the atom package "Remote-FTP" and using a private key.

I have the SSH keys set up on my server and can connect successfully using putty.

The private key is saved in my project folder and I have an existing .ftpconfig file (without a private key) that connects successfully when I replace the information inside the file.

The Key has been converted to the necessary ssh format and I have no passphrase at the moment. I have also gave the full path of the private key file

Here is my .ftpconfig file -

```
{
"protocol": "sftp",
"host": "user@server",
"port": 22,
"user": "",
"pass": "",
"promptForPass": false,
"remote": "",
"local": "",
"agent": "",
"privatekey": "putty_private_key_sbappsupconvrted.ppk",
"passphrase": "",
"hosthash": "",
"ignorehost": true,
"connTimeout": 10000,
"keepalive": 10000,
"keyboardInteractive": true,
"watch": [],
"watchTimeout": 500
}
```

The error code I am receiving is:

> REMOTE FTP: Connection...
>
> REMOTE FTP: Connection failed Error: getaddrinfo EAI_FAIL user@server:
>   22
>
> REMOTE FTP: Connection closed

I have also given the full path of the private key file

```
C:\Users\user\.atom\server\putty_private_key_sbappsupconvrted.ppk
```

and I get this error

> Could not parse .ftpconfig Unexpected token U in JSON at position 219

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `"host": "user@server",` Surely this value should just be the server name, and the user name should go with the "user" key.

Comment: When logging into Putty using the SSH key the hostname is user@server. However, I just tried this and it worked! I had to use "putty_private_key_sbappsupconvrted.ppk". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your private key in following path: `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.30.0`

Replace `USER`. It seems it looks in this folder for the keys.

Comment: I do this now as well. Whenever there is an update you have to move the private key to the new version though.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is the backslashes. The .ftpconfig file is in JSON format and slash followed by character has a special meaning. To use your ssh key you just have to escape the slashes. In other words change :

`C:\Users\user\.atom\server\putty_private_key_sbappsupconvrted.ppk`

To :

`C:\\Users\\user\\.atom\\server\\putty_private_key_sbappsupconvrted.ppk`

Then it will work with no issues.