# JSON parse Windows file path

Tags: json, atom-editor

I want to specify a windows file path in my remote-ftp Atom configuration to reference my private key but I get some parsing issues. Here's my configuration:

```
{
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "host": "somehost.com",
    "port": 22,
    "user": "haha",
    "pass": "testpass",
    "promptForPass": false,
    "remote": "/",
    "local": "",
    "agent": "",
    "privatekey": "C:\Users\haha\Documents\Keys\test_private_key.ppk",
    "passphrase": "",
    "hosthash": "",
    "ignorehost": true,
    "connTimeout": 10000,
    "keepalive": 10000,
    "keyboardInteractive": false,
    "keyboardInteractiveForPass": false,
    "remoteCommand": "",
    "remoteShell": "",
    "watch": [],
    "watchTimeout": 500
}
```

With the error:

**Parse Error: "privatekey": "C:\Users\haha\Docum**

So any idea how i escape Windows file paths for JSON parsing?

Comment: I forget, but it may be a problem with the backslashes. Try putting \\  everywhere that you have \ and see if the issue persists.

Comment: When I do this, I get 'unexpected token "h" at position 268' (the start of haha in that line)

Comment: Can you copy-paste that entire line here, with the error message you are getting? There may just be a simple typo somewhere.

Comment: `"privatekey": "C:\\Users\\haha\\Documents\\Keys\\test_private_key.ppk",` should be all you need to do,

Comment: ```"privatekey": "C:\\Users\\haha\\Documents\\Keys\\test_private_key.ppk",```

Unexpected token h in JSON at position 268

Comment: Thank you! That looks right to me. Are you absolutely sure that you are looking at the correct line and position? If so, why is the position so high? (>200)

Comment: Yes I'm absolutely sure. However, I've found a question which may be related and it could be an Atom specific problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152008/issue-connection-to-server-using-remote-ftp-atom-package-and-private-keys as it appears you need your private key accessible in Window app data

Comment: Good find, that may be the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, since backslashes need to be escaped per [spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html#:%7E:text=a%20string%20is%20a%20sequence%20of%20zero%20or%20more%20unicode%20characters%2C%20wrapped%20in%20double%20quotes%2C%20using%20backslash%20escapes).

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes

Hence, the value of `privateKey` should be `"C:\\Users\\haha\\Documents\\Keys\\test_private_key.ppk"`.