# Atom editor cannot create SFTP connection to AWS Ubuntu instance using remote-ftp 2.2.4

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to connect remotely to a Ubuntu 18.04 instance on AWS using `remote-ftp 2.2.4` from my local machine running Windows 10.

I have my `.ftpconfig` file at `D:\Webserver`, and have entered that value into `remote-ftp's` settings.

My `.pem` file is at `C:/myKey.pem`

But when I try to connect I keep getting

```
Remote FTP: Could not read .ftpconfig file.

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

Where am I going wrong? This is my `.ftpconfig` file.

```
{
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "host": "00.000.0.00",
    "port": 22,
    "user": "ubuntu",
    "pass": "",
    "promptForPass": false,
    "remote": "/",
    "local": "",
    "agent": "",
    "privatekey": "C:/myKey.pem",
    "passphrase": "",
    "hosthash": "",
    "ignorehost": true,
    "connTimeout": 10000,
    "keepalive": 10000,
    "keyboardInteractive": false,
    "keyboardInteractiveForPass": false,
    "remoteCommand": "",
    "remoteShell": "",
    "watch": [],
    "watchTimeout": 500
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be other posts out there talking about the same error

[NPM stuck giving the same error EISDIR: Illegal operation on a directory, read at error (native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a)

If you have git installed on windows, you can use the sftp command that ships with git bash. To use it open the git bash shell and run below command:

```
sftp -i /path/to/pemfile.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4
```

EDIT: 
The issue seems to be the privatekey property. This post mentions you need to escape the back slashes

[Issue Connection to server using Remote-FTP atom package and Private Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152008/issue-connection-to-server-using-remote-ftp-atom-package-and-private-keys?rq=1)

Also below documentation mentions "Path to the private key file (in OpenSSH format).". Also Try `/myKey.pem` or `/c/myKey.pem`

http://github-atom-io-staging-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/packages/remote-ftp